# "Limited" wifi on my Windows machine

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

Recently I changed the wifi router because the previous one got worn out. Since then I am not able to open any website on my laptop. It says the connection is "Limited". So, I formatted my machine but still the problem persists. Other laptop with Windows 8.1 works very well on the same wifi router. Even other devices like tablet and smartphones work fine.

So, I went to my friend's place to check if my laptop works on his wifi. But still the same problem!

I can only access the internet if I am using the LAN cable directly connected to the router.

Its been about a month since my laptop has become a desktop! How do I fix this wifi issue?

Comment: Could you connect the WiFi as limited > Right click on the start ORB and go to command prompt > type ipconfig /all > press enter > paste the results back in this question for me to review, thanks.

Comment: which laptop are you using?

Comment: Formatting your machine is a pretty drastic solution to a networking issue. The fact that you get a connection (even if it is limited) points to a configuration issue rather than hardware. Next time, consider posting here first! ;-)  I'd imagine you have a misconfigured wireless connection (maybe with a fixed IP, or broken DNS/DHCP configuration, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the output of `ipconfig /all` to see where you are right now.

I would guess that your WiFi interface needs to set IP address to be obtained automatically (use DHCP) or you may just need to disconnect from WiFi and retype your WiFi password again.

Additionally, I would also try to update your WiFi drivers to the latest version just in case. You can download the drivers on another laptop and transfer it using USB flash drive.